# Cannot scroll terminal in Fedora CLI

Tags: fedora, console

I work on Fedora 17 entirely in CLI (or TUI) and I do not have a mouse. If I output something that is long I cannot scroll the lines.

I tried <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> as some sites suggest but none let me scroll the terminal.

Is there a universal way to let me scroll the terminal line by line?

Comment: There isn't a universal method, so this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying various combination, it is <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> that works for me.

Environment: running **Fedora 17 CLI/TUI** on **VMWare Fusion 3** on **OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard**.

Comment: As you said that you don't have a "Page up" key and considering that "fn + arrow up" corresponds to "Page up" on a Mac I think you made an error in your answer. Should it not be "shift + fn + up"?

Comment: thanks @Matteo you are correct. Answers amended. Is Up, not Page-up

Answer (score 6):

Usually it is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> to scroll up and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> to scroll down.

Comment: Unless you switch desktops (VTs). Switching desktops clears the scrollback and it might seem like these keys have no effect.

Comment: I'm running Fedora on VMWare on Macbook Pro which doesn't have page up or down key. The track pad doesn't scroll either. I also tried the fn key but no luck.